# Is there any way to get the access token of the user who is log in to FBMessenger

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-messenger

I am able to open my `FBMessenger` from my application. (And my application is logged in through Facebook, So I have the access token of the user who logged into my application). By clicking the chat button I am able to open messenger, But I need to check whether the user Logged in messenger is the same user in my application or not. So`I need the access token of the user who logged in the messenger (installed on his phone)`.

Comment: i don´t think that this is possible. why would you need to know anyway? what is the use case?

Comment: We are allowing a user to login from facebook using Facebook IOS SDK.  every time the "login in with facebook" button is clicked the fb login web view is displayed and user has to enter his credentials. Once he enters valid credentials he is logged into our application. Once he is in our applciaiton, there is a chat icon, on clicking of it, the facebook message dialog is displayed.

Comment: The problem here is there is a logged in user in phones FB messenger who is different from the user logged into our application using facebook. We need to open the FB Message dialog using the logged in user of our app but not the user who is already logged into the mobile FB messenger.

Comment: that is weird, why would a user have two different facebook accounts on his phone? or do i get this wrong?

Comment: Our use case is that any person in an organization can use that mobile to use our application.